# Seeking an analytic proof of a vector identity

Tags: vector-spaces

> Show that for any vectors $\bf{u_1},\bf{u_2},\bf{v_1},\bf{v_2}\in\mathbb R^3$, we have $$(\bf{u_1}\times\bf{v_1})\cdot(\bf{u_2}\times\bf{v_2})=
> \left|\begin{matrix}
> \bf{u_1}\cdot\bf{u_2} & \bf{u_1}\cdot\bf{v_2}\\
> \bf{v_1}\cdot\bf{u_2} & \bf{v_1}\cdot\bf{v_2}
> \end{matrix} \right|.$$

I really don't want to "explode" it, is there a more analytic way to prove this identity? Thanks.

Comment: The box product is related to the determinant of the components. This would account for a smaller explosion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First note that,

$(\vec a\times\vec b)\cdot\vec c=\vec a\cdot(\vec b\times\vec c)$

and then

[$\vec a\times(\vec b\times\vec c)=(\vec a\cdot\vec c)\vec b-(\vec a\cdot\vec b)\vec c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/167758/33989)

**EDIT**:  Consider $u_1=\vec a,$ $v_1=\vec b$ and $\vec c=(u_2\times v_2),$  then, $(u_1\times v_1)\cdot(u_2\times v_2)=u_1\cdot(v_1\times(u_2\times v_2))$

Now use second identity to expand $v_1\times(u_2\times v_2)$

Comment: ??? there is no double cross product here

Comment: @O.L. Consider $\vec c=(u_2\times v_2)$, then, $(u_1\times v_1)\cdot(u_2\times v_2)=u_1\cdot(v_1\times(u_2\times v_2))$

Comment: How to prove the identity on the second line?

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ: i've added a link for the proof to the identity

Answer (score 4):

**An approach without too much calculation**

The map $f:x\mapsto (\bf{u_1}\times\bf{v_1}$$)\cdot($$\bf{u_2}\times\bf{x}$$)$ is a linear form with kernel $\ker f= \langle\bf{u_2}\rangle$ and similary the map

$$g: x\mapsto\left|\begin{matrix}
\bf{u_1}\cdot\bf{u_2} & \bf{u_1}\cdot\bf{x}\\
\bf{v_1}\cdot\bf{u_2} & \bf{v_1}\cdot\bf{x}
\end{matrix} \right|$$ is a linear form and $\ker f=\ker g$ hence we conclude that there's $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ such that $f=\lambda g$. Now take  $\bf{u_1}=\bf{u_2}$ and $\bf{v_1}=\bf{v_2}$ and $\bf{u_1}\perp \bf{v_1}$ and we find $\lambda=1$